# PHP telegram bot reply_mark

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm programming a bot on telegram and I didn't make the special keyboard via reply_mark up someone can help me?
My code is this:

```
file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$myID."&text=keyTest&reply_markup={"keyboard":[["test"]]}");
```

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: The code doesnt work! And I don't know how to do!

Comment: @user3649959 there isn't enough context here for us to understand the problem. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Do you get anything at all? Are you sure it's this line that's at fault; Is there any other code around it that might be contributing? What are the values in the variables? etc etc etc... you need to give a load more info before anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I just test all the code and without this line work perfectly, my friends told me that wrong part is the final more probably. reply_markup={"keyboard":[["test"]]}"); Because I try this line by URL and bot send me message and change layout showing a bug button with text "test"

Answer (score 0):

If I copy&paste your parameters to my bot and execute the command it works. But that's because I use the Text you provide as parts of my url.

```
api.telegram.org/bot[key]/sendMessage?chat_id=[id]&text=keyTest&reply_markup={"keyboard":[["test"]]}
```

What you are doing is writing a script that executes the command. As far as I can tell you're using the dot `.` to concatenate strings. Another thing you're doing is trying to write the JSON for the reply_markup directly into the url.

What your problem probably is, is one of the following: You're not escaping the `"` sign **or** not concatenating variables correctly.

So if `keyboard` and `test` are variables you need to concatenate them correctly using the dot:

```
file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$myID."&text=keyTest&reply_markup={".$keyboard.":[[".$test."]]}");
```

but if you just want to write your test keyboard into the string you need to escape the `"` so your string does not end:

```
file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$myID."&text=keyTest&reply_markup={\"keyboard\":[[\"test\"]]}");
```

Note: I have no idea if this is the correct way to escape `"` in php. This is just to explain your error. If you need to escape double quotes in php any other way, do it how it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think that I have the solution for you!
So, this is the code:

```
$key = "{\"keyboard\":[ [\"OPTION1\"], [\"OPTION2\"], [\"OPTION3\"] ]}";
$url = $GLOBALS[API_URL]."/sendmessage?chat_id=$id&text=Choose%20your%20action&reply_markup=".urlencode($key);
file_get_contents($url);
```

Variable $GLOBALS[API_URL] = https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:AAf6g4fr4rt5y67hadsffaerafasfasf
So replace my global var with your direct url or whatever :D
Other function that should be interesting for you is this:

```
function close_keyboard($id, $message)
{       
    //$text = "Keyboard_closed!";
    $message = str_replace(" ", "%20", $message);
    $key = "{\"hide_keyboard\":true}";
    $url = $GLOBALS[API_URL]."/sendmessage?chat_id=$id&text=$messagge&reply_markup=".urlencode($key);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

This function close your custom keyboard, and other my personal function is this:

```
function build_keyboard($elements, $message, $chat_id)
{
    //Get length of array
    $len = count($elements);

    //Build custom keyboard
    $keyboard = "{\"keyboard\":[ [\"";
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i)
    {
        if($i < $len-1)
            $keyboard .= $elements[$i]."\"],[\"";
        else
            $keyboard .= $elements[$i]."\"] ]}";
    }

    $url = $GLOBALS[API_URL]."/sendmessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=".urlencode($message)."&reply_markup=".urlencode($keyboard);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Prototype of this function is build_keyboard(array(), String, String)
Example:

```
$messagge = "Wrong choise";
$keyboard = array("OPT1", "OPT2", "OPT3");
build_keyboard($keyboard, $message, $chat_id);
```

Remember that $message is always needed or reply_doesntt work!

Hope this will be usefull! You're welcome!